# What are the security implications of storing a CA password for local development only in a repository?

Tags: certificate-authority

During local development of our website we need some [features that are restricted to secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts/features_restricted_to_secure_contexts), meaning we need a self signed certificate for 'localhost' for some things to work.

To make things as easy as possible for new developers to spin up a local development server, I've created a script that creates a new certificate authority that then signs a certificate used for the local server. Developers can then add the CA to their trusted root certificates to prevent the browser from showing security warnings.

However, the script I'm using uses a password to generate the CA key, and since the script is included in the repository, so is the password. What are the security implications of this, if any?

Since a new CA key is generated every time you run the script, I would assume this method is safe as long as the generated CA is not used for anything else and stays on the machine of the developer that generated it. But I'm not entirely sure if reusing the same passphrase on every machine means that newly created CAs can be abused somehow.

The script I'm using to generate the certificates was loosely taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/3625298) and looks like this

```
PASSPHRASE='my-passphrase'
mkdir tmp

openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$PASSPHRASE -out tmp/ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes \
-passin pass:$PASSPHRASE \
-key tmp/ca.key \
-sha256 -days 825 \
-out ca.pem \
-subj '/O=My Certificate Authority'

openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048
openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out tmp/signRequest.csr \
-subj '/O=My Certificate Authority /CN=localhost'

>tmp/config.ext cat <<-EOF
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = localhost.example.com
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
EOF

openssl x509 -req -in tmp/signRequest.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey tmp/ca.key -CAcreateserial \
-passin pass:$PASSPHRASE \
-out $NAME.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile tmp/config.ext
```

Note that I'm aware that most features restricted to secure contexts still work when using 'localhost' as domain. However, I've found that many things such as third party OAuth don't allow you to redirect to localhost directly, which is why I've also added 'localhost.example.com' to the certificate. Which can then be pointed to 127.0.0.1 using a hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

We can safely assume it is safe.

The problem is not the password, which can be as easy as `my-password`, but the CA certificate and the process of trusting it in the trust store.

You said that the certificate is generated every time the script is run, and perhaps it is run only when the developer sets the environment up.

The password, in this case, is not sensitive material, and I would suggest to remove it completely (passwordless CA). Only sensitive material is CA private key, which again is local to the computer.

You must, however, rememember that trusting a certificate is a sensitive operation as soon as someone may generate a valid certificate for `stackexchange.com` from a self-signed (or company-local) CA.

You should only instruct your developers to bury the certificate.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware passwordless CA was possible, I'll try that. For macOS I'm generating a certificate without a CA. That way only localhost.example.com can be controlled should the certificate be compromised. Unfortunately I haven't yet been able to find a way to trust only a specific cert on Linux, so I had to resort to trusting an entire root CA.